# Create both an int and string from an extracted json in jmeter

Tags: testing, jmeter, automated-tests, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I'm currently running some performance tests and am having issues converting a string I have extracted from JSON into an int.

The problem I'm having is that I need this number which has been extracted as both an int and a string, its currently only a string and I don't see how I can create another variable where the number is an int.

Here is the JSON extractor I'm using

[image: Json Extractor]

How can I have another variable which is an int?

Comment: What will you do with int you can't do with string?

Comment: Im adding it to another request later in the test, for some reason it accepts int rather than strings in one of my requests

Comment: Show the code you need to change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default JMeter stores values into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) in [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) form, if you need to save it in Integer form as well you can do it using i.e. [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) like:

```
${__groovy(vars.putObject('Fixture_ID_INT'\, vars.get('Fixture_ID') as int),)}
```

and access it where required like:

```
${__groovy(vars.getObject('Fixture_ID_INT'),)}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below code

```
Integer.parseInt(vars.get("urs"));
```